# Notification Categories

Tags: ionic-framework

I have created one of the mobile application using ionic 1 and firebase. Now I want to create a notification categories like channel where user can select which notification they needed.

Here I have shared the code for push notification which i have used and this code is working , i want to create the notification categories, the above code is working for push notification for my mobile application.

Now I need a help that how can I create the channel notification categories in my mobile application

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
    if(data.wasTapped){
      //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
      alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
    }else{
      //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
      alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Anantha Raju will you help me